# C# recursive generics in generics

Tags: c#, generics

I am playing with DDD for some time and have found [Ayende's base class](http://ayende.com/blog/2500/generic-entity-equality) construction for an Entity. I would like to construct a base assembly with only the most necessary objects. This is what I came up with (simplified without implementation):

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<T, TKey> where T : BaseEntity<T, TKey> { }

public interface IAggregateRoot { }

public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Commit();
}

// I am open to changes if they help
public interface IWriteUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    void Insert<TAggregateRoot, T, TKey>(TAggregateRoot aggregateRoot)
        where TAggregateRoot : BaseEntity<T, TKey>, IAggregateRoot
        where T : BaseEntity<T, TKey>;
}
```

Everything is fine untill I use this constructions in a project. This are the specifics of the project simplified without an implementation:

```
public abstract class Entity : BaseEntity<Entity, Guid> { }

public class Customer : Entity, IAggregateRoot { }

public abstract class Context : IWriteUnitOfWork
{
    public void Insert<TAggregateRoot, T, TKey>(TAggregateRoot aggregateRoot)
        where TAggregateRoot : BaseEntity<T, TKey>, IAggregateRoot
        where T : BaseEntity<T, TKey> { }

    public void Commit() { }
}

public class MyContext : Context { }

public class ExampleThatWorks
{
    public void Something()
    {
        IWriteUnitOfWork myContext = new MyContext();
        var customer = new Customer();

        // this works
        myContext.Insert<Customer, Entity, Guid>(customer);
    }
}

public class ExampleThatIWant
{
    public void Something()
    {
        IWriteUnitOfWork myContext = new MyContext();
        var customer = new Customer();

        // this doesn't work
        myContext.Insert(customer);
    }
}
```

My problem is with the Insert method from IWriteUnitOfWork interface. I would like it written so that I don't have to write all the generic stuff every time I want to use it as in ExampleThatIWant. Yet, I wouldn't like to change my base assembly if there isn't a really good reason for it.

Is this possible and how? I am open to other approaches as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<T, TKey> where T : BaseEntity<T, TKey> { }

public interface IAggregateRoot { }

public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Commit();
}

public interface IWriteUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    void Insert<T>(T aggregateRoot)
        where T : BaseEntity<T, Guid>, IAggregateRoot;
}

public abstract class Entity<T, TKey> : BaseEntity<T, TKey>
    where T : BaseEntity<T, TKey>
{ }

public class Customer : Entity<Customer, Guid>, IAggregateRoot { }

public abstract class Context : IWriteUnitOfWork
{
    public void Insert<T>(T aggregateRoot)
        where T : BaseEntity<T, Guid>, IAggregateRoot
    { }

    public void Commit() { }
}

public class MyContext : Context { }

public class ExampleThatIWant
{
    public void Something()
    {
        IWriteUnitOfWork myContext = new MyContext();
        var customer = new Customer();

        myContext.Insert(customer);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you described what was the improvement

Comment: The compiler can't infer both types T and TKey (or 3 in the original example), so if we limit it to one type in the insert function it compiles without specifying all the generic parameters. The downside is that you can only have Guid keys in the context, which is probably fine.

Comment: Unfortunetely, no. You have written the downside yourself. Guid is my preffered choice of primary key, but with this solution I don't have the necessary flexibility that I'm looking for. Anyway thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend using a repository approach then: Separate the repository part (insert, update, delete etc...) from the UnitOfWork.